# Filling VB.net datatable with result of SQl query (link to microsoft access relational database)

Tags: vb.net

Hello I was wondering if someone could help me.
I need to output the result of an SQL query on a relational database. I wanted the output to be just like the table you see if you execute the query in Microsoft Access.  For this I used a VB.net Data Grid. I see the result of simple queries such as...

"SELECT * FROM Form;"

however if I try to add any more detail to the SQL statement than that (even just a WHERE), the code throws the error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'
The specific SQL statement I need is...

"SELECT [Student data].[Student First Name], [Student data].[Student Last Name], [Student data].Severity, [Student data].[Form group] FROM Form INNER JOIN [Student data] ON Form.[Form group] = [Student data].[Form group] WHERE ((([Student data].Severity)= High));"

This is my current simple code that works:

```
Private Sub data_table()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "
        datafile = "P:\Documents\SCHOOL WORK\A level\COMPUTER SCIENCE\PROJECT\Visual basic\Student Data.accdb"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Form;", myconnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(reader)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

And this is the code which shows the error:

```
Private Sub data_table()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "
        datafile = "P:\Documents\SCHOOL WORK\A level\COMPUTER SCIENCE\PROJECT\Visual basic\Student Data.accdb"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Student data].[Student First Name], [Student data]. [Student Last Name], [Student data].Severity, [Student data].[Form group] FROM Form INNER JOIN [Student data] ON Form.[Form group] = [Student data].[Form group] WHERE ((([Student data].Severity)= High));", myconnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(reader)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Please can you help me I'm quite lost.
Thank you :)

Comment: Check the column names for typos. Also there is a space after the dot in: `[Student data]. [Student Last Name]`. Remove it.

Comment: If you replace High to 'High', will it work? It seems that you have omitted the apostrophes which should be wrapped around text literals.

Comment: Thank you so much my code now works!!! I've been staring at that code for two days trying to figure out the error. It was such a simple one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most database objects need to be not only closed but also disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error. A single Using block handles both the connection and the command here.

Once the connection and command are closed and disposed by the `End Using`, we update the user interface.

I really don't get why you needed a Join in your query. All the data was being pulled from the same table and the Where clause referenced the same table.

```
Private Sub data_table()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\Documents\SCHOOL WORK\A level\COMPUTER SCIENCE\PROJECT\Visual basic\Student Data.accdb;"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT 
                            [Student First Name], 
                            [Student Last Name], 
                            Severity, 
                            [Form group] 
                            FROM [Student data]  WHERE Severity= 'High'));", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```